# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hcaptcha'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, hcaptcha

I am trying to execute a code of mine, but i keep getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hcaptcha'

When I try installing 'hcaptcha' from pip install hcaptcha, it say this:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hcaptcha (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for hcaptcha

I tried installing captcha and recaptcha too, but the error was still the same that hcaptcha module is not found.

Here is the bit of my code which is affected:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import cv2, hcaptcha
import numpy as np

model = load_model('./data/data.h5')
```

i will not show rest of it, only this much of it is important since this contains the import hcaptcha

Comment: I think you need to tell us what this hcaptcha module is, it is not in pypi, are you sure its not a custom module that you or another person made?

Answer (score 0):

The hcaptcha library is one made by h0nde
Just Install With The Following:
(Make Sure You Have Git Installed)

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/h0nde/py-hcaptcha
```